# ¿Cómo puedo unir el valor de una columna de un dataframe por un guión en r?

Tags: r

Tengo una columna en el que tengo tipos de especies de bacterias, por ejemplo: saccharomyces cerevisiae. Y quiero unir sus valores mediante un guión. De tal forma que quede: saccharomyces-cerevisiae. He visto que con la función unite() se puede hacer para unir dos columnas. Pero si en vez de dos columnas, ¿quiero unir el valor dentro de la misma columna?

Comment: Reemplaza el espacio por un guion: `gsub(" ", "-", tu_columna)`

Comment: Sería con paste0()  ---> paste0(saccharomyces, "-", cerevisiae)